# Actions on Google / API.ai agent - use my own app without saying app name

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Just purchased a Google Home and created an app using API.ai, which works fine in the 'Actions on Google' simulator. I don't plan to publish this app (it's very specific to me - it just calls a webhook on my webserver with a couple of entities taken from the command)...but I'd ideally like to use commands (intents) without having to confirm each time that I want to use my app.

I realise I can set my intents as 'triggers', but Google Assistant still asks if I'd like to use [my app name] and I have to confirm. Is there any way to automatically make it use my app if my voice command matches a trigger?

Comment: You probably want to try "action invocation phrase":
https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit

I think I have done this once, months ago. I am not sure if this will fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @SysCoder - I tried that but it comes back with "you might want to talk to  _app name_, does that sound good?" and you have to confirm. Ideally I'm just looking for a way of saying "do this to that" and it'll call the fulfilment webhook. Seems to work via IFTTT...but would like a little more flexibility.

Comment: Again, it has been a while since I have done this. But are you doing the explicit invocation vs. implicit invocation? With the explicit, you should *not* have to setup additional triggers as shown here: developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit and it shouldn't ask you for confirmation. I don't think explicit gives you exactly what you want, but I think it is close.

Comment: Yes explicit invocation work fine, I was just hoping to match the way it works with (for example) IFTTT - I say a command and it immediately fulfills it, you never mention the app name (you don't even mention IFTTT). I'm guessing it may not be possible for self-created apps. 'Shortcuts' in Google Assistant come close as a possible workaround, but they don't allow wildcard words.

Comment: @Chris did you ever come around this?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I've ended up doing what I can with IFTTT, using a voice command to call a webhook rather than creating my own app. They seem to have some kind of special permission which gives them the ability to do this.